# String parser with boost variant recursive wrapper

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-variant

The code below (adapted from spirit qi mini_xml example) does not compile. There is an error related to the rule `brac` that has an attribute of an recursive `boost::variant`.
However, all commented out versions of `brac` do compile.

I am very curious to know what makes the simple string parser so special in this case:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace client
{
   namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
   namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
   namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
   namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

   struct ast_node;

   typedef boost::variant<
      boost::recursive_wrapper<ast_node>,
      std::string
   > ast_branch;

   struct ast_node
   {
      std::string text;
      std::vector<ast_branch> children;
   };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
      client::ast_node,
      (std::string, text)
      (std::vector<client::ast_branch>, children)
)

namespace client
{
   template <typename Iterator>
      struct ast_node_grammar
      : qi::grammar<Iterator, ast_branch(), ascii::space_type>
      {
         ast_node_grammar()
            : ast_node_grammar::base_type(brac)
         {
            using qi::_1;
            using qi::_val;
            using ascii::char_;
            using ascii::string;

            name %= *char_;

            brac %= string("no way") ;
//            brac = string("works")[_val = _1] ;
//            brac %= string("this") | string("works");
//            brac %= name ; // works
//            brac %= *char_ ; // works
         }
         qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> name;
         qi::rule<Iterator, ast_branch(), ascii::space_type> brac;
      };
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   typedef client::ast_node_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> ast_node_grammar;
   ast_node_grammar gram;
   client::ast_branch ast;

   std::string text("dummy");
   using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
   std::string::const_iterator iter = text.begin();
   std::string::const_iterator end = text.end();
   bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, gram, space, ast);
   return r ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Part of the error message:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:38:17: error: No match for ‘boost::variant<
        boost::recursive_wrapper<client::ast_node>, basic_string<char> 
>::variant(
        const __normal_iterator<const char *, basic_string<char> > &, const __normal_iterator<
            const char *, basic_string<char> > &)’
```

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest the problem is Attribute compatibility. Contrary to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/string.html), the ascii::string parser appears to expose an *iterator range* instead of a *string*.

```
name = string("no way");
```

is no issue, because the attribute exposed by ascii::string can be coerced into the rule's attribute type without any difficulty.

However, the `brac` rule's attribute type is `ast_branch`, which is only a *variant* with one of it's possible contained types. Therefore, the `ast_branch` type has several constructors, and it isn't clear to Spirit which one is adequate for this particular conversion.

There are several ways about this (besides the approaches you already showed):

- use `attr_cast`

  ```
  brac = qi::attr_cast( string("no way") );
  ```
- use `as_string`

  ```
  brac = qi::as_string[ string("no way") ];
  ```
- use customization points

  ```
  namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
      template <typename It>
          struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<client::ast_branch, It>
          {
              static void call(It const& f, It const& l, client::ast_branch& val)
              {
                  val = std::string(f, l);
              }
          };
  }}}
  ```

Each of these have the same effect: make Spirit realize what attribute conversion to use.

Here is a full working sample showing all three:

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace client
{
   namespace fusion  = boost::fusion;
   namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
   namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
   namespace ascii   = boost::spirit::ascii;

   struct ast_node;

   typedef boost::variant<
      boost::recursive_wrapper<ast_node>,
      std::string
   > ast_branch;

   struct ast_node
   {
      std::string text;
      std::vector<ast_branch> children;
   };
}

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
        struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<client::ast_branch, It>
        {
            static void call(It const& f, It const& l, client::ast_branch& val)
            {
                val = std::string(f, l);
            }
        };
}}}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
      client::ast_node,
      (std::string, text)
      (std::vector<client::ast_branch>, children)
)

namespace client
{
    template <typename Iterator>
        struct ast_node_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ast_branch(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        ast_node_grammar()
            : ast_node_grammar::base_type(brac)
        {
            using qi::_1;
            using qi::_val;
            using ascii::char_;
            using ascii::string;

            name %= *char_;

            brac = string("works");
            brac = string("works")[_val = _1] ;
            brac %= string("this") | string("works");
            brac %= name ; // works
            brac %= *char_ ; // works

            brac = qi::as_string[ string("no way") ];
            brac = qi::attr_cast( string("no way") );
        }
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> name;
        qi::rule<Iterator, ast_branch(), ascii::space_type> brac;
    };
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   typedef client::ast_node_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> ast_node_grammar;
   ast_node_grammar gram;
   client::ast_branch ast;

   std::string text("dummy");
   using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
   std::string::const_iterator iter = text.begin();
   std::string::const_iterator end = text.end();
   bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, gram, space, ast);
   return r ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: The hint to assign_to_attribute_from_iterators was nice.

Comment: @pdug thanks! Welcome to [SO]. Remember to [vote/accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so people will know what answers helped the OP

Comment: I've found this answer using a dart-style google query. That's certainly a documentation bug that `qi::string` generates `std::string`. Though it seems that they know about it, and made `qi::as_string[...]` syntax pretty much for this case.